# Oracle SQL 10g query for creating comma separated records

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, string-aggregation

I am writing an oracle 10g query for creating jasper reports.

This is the query -

```
SELECT     essay_id,
           LTRIM (
              MAX (SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (full_name, ','))
                 KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY curr),
              ',')
              AS full_name
FROM       (SELECT essay_id,
                   full_name,
                   ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY essay_id ORDER BY full_name)
                      AS curr,
                     ROW_NUMBER ()
                        OVER (PARTITION BY essay_id ORDER BY full_name)
                   - 1
                      AS prev
            FROM   (SELECT a.id AS essay_id,
                           CASE NVL (firstname, 'NULL FIRSTNAME')
                              WHEN 'NULL FIRSTNAME' THEN username
                              ELSE (firstname || ' ' || lastname)
                           END
                              AS full_name
                    FROM   essay_table a
                           INNER JOIN essay_writer_join ej ON a.id = ej.essay_id
                           INNER JOIN writer_table u ON ej.user_id = u.id))
GROUP BY   essay_id
CONNECT BY prev = PRIOR curr AND essay_id = PRIOR essay_id
START WITH curr = 1
```

The essays are unique but can have multiple writers (essay_writer_join)
This query gives me essays with the writers which are separated by comma.

The problem is I need to add one more column called "manager" that will show the manager of the writer. The manager information is in the WRITER_TABLE with column name "manager_name". The essay_table has the writers first name, last name and username.  The tricky part is that 2 writers can have 2 different managers.
For example for essay '123' the writers are 'abc' and 'xyz' and the managers for these writers are 'lmo' and 'pqr' respectively then the records should indicate in following format

```
essay id      writer       manager
123          abc, xyz      lmo, pqr
```

Is this possible in oracle 10g sql?
I tried to search for similar situation but cannot find any related solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just include the `manager_name` in the innermost query and the middle query, and then repeat the aggregation mechanism for that column too. I've change the column and table aliases to be a bit more consistent (and I've also simplified your case expression):

```
SELECT     essay_id,
           LTRIM (
              MAX (SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (writer, ','))
                 KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY curr),
              ',')
              AS writer,
           LTRIM (
              MAX (SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (manager, ','))
                 KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY curr),
              ',')
              AS manager
FROM       (SELECT essay_id,
                   writer,
                   manager,
                   ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY essay_id ORDER BY writer)
                      AS curr,
                     ROW_NUMBER ()
                        OVER (PARTITION BY essay_id ORDER BY writer)
                   - 1
                      AS prev
            FROM   (SELECT et.id AS essay_id,
                           CASE WHEN wt.firstname IS NULL THEN wt.username
                              ELSE (wt.firstname || ' ' || wt.lastname)
                           END
                              AS writer,
                           wt.manager_name as manager
                    FROM   essay_table et
                           INNER JOIN essay_writer_join ej ON et.id = ej.essay_id
                           INNER JOIN writer_table wt ON ej.user_id = wt.id))
GROUP BY   essay_id
CONNECT BY prev = PRIOR curr AND essay_id = PRIOR essay_id
START WITH curr = 1;

  ESSAY_ID WRITER     MANAGER  
---------- ---------- ----------
       123 abc,xyz    lmo,pqr
```

The only real issue I can see is if both writer of an essay have the same manager; then you'd see the value repeated:

```
  ESSAY_ID WRITER     MANAGER  
---------- ---------- ----------
       123 abc,xyz    lmo,pqr   
       456 abc,def    lmo,lmo
```

That may be what you want to see though.

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/958a4/1).

If you do want to suppress the duplicate managers you can separate the aggregation into subqueries. I find it easier to read with these pulled on into common table expressions (a.k.a. subquery refactoring):

```
WITH all_data AS (
  SELECT et.id AS essay_id,
         CASE WHEN wt.firstname IS NULL THEN wt.username
            ELSE (wt.firstname || ' ' || wt.lastname)
         END
            AS writer,
         wt.manager_name as manager
  FROM   essay_table et
  JOIN   essay_writer_join ej ON et.id = ej.essay_id
  JOIN   writer_table wt ON ej.user_id = wt.id
),
writers AS (
  SELECT essay_id,
         writer,
         ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY essay_id ORDER BY writer) AS rn
  FROM   (
    SELECT distinct essay_id, writer
    FROM   all_data
  )
),
managers AS (
  SELECT essay_id,
         manager,
         ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY essay_id ORDER BY manager) AS rn
  FROM   (
    SELECT distinct essay_id, manager
    FROM   all_data
  )
)
SELECT   DISTINCT ad.essay_id,
         (
           SELECT     LTRIM (MAX (SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (w.writer, ','))
                        KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY w.rn), ',')
           FROM       writers w
           WHERE      w.essay_id = ad.essay_id
           CONNECT BY w.rn = PRIOR w.rn + 1 AND w.essay_id = PRIOR w.essay_id
           START WITH w.rn = 1
         ) AS writer,
         (
           SELECT     LTRIM (MAX (SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (m.manager, ','))
                        KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY m.rn), ',')
           FROM       managers m
           WHERE      m.essay_id = ad.essay_id
           CONNECT BY m.rn = PRIOR m.rn + 1 AND m.essay_id = PRIOR m.essay_id
           START WITH m.rn = 1
         ) AS manager
FROM     all_data ad
ORDER BY ad.essay_id;
```

The important bit is that each subquery that assigns the row numbers uses its own inline view to get the distinct values. So for the same data that gets:

```
  ESSAY_ID WRITER     MANAGER  
---------- ---------- ----------
       123 abc,xyz    lmo,pqr   
       456 abc,def    lmo
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/958a4/4).

Comment: Great answer! It worked like a charm and I needed repeat values but good to know how to remove them. Thanks!